# Convert a Vec<u16> or Vec<WCHAR> to a &str

Tags: string, rust

I'm getting into Rust programming to realize a small program and I'm a little bit lost in string conversions.

In my program, I have a vector as follows:

```
let mut name: Vec<winnt::WCHAR> = Vec::new();
```

`WCHAR` is the same as a `u16` on my Windows machine.

I hand over the `Vec<u16>` to a C function (as a pointer) which fills it with data. I then need to convert the string contained in the vector into a  `&str`. However, no matter, what I try, I can not manage to get this conversion working.

The only thing I managed to get working is to convert it to a `WideString`:

```
 widestr = unsafe { WideCString::from_ptr_str(name.as_ptr()) };
```

But this seems to be a step into the wrong direction.

What is the best way to convert the `Vec<u16>` to an `&str` under the assumption that the vector holds a valid and null-terminated string.

Answer (score 13):

> I then need to convert the string contained in the vector into a `&str`. However, no matter, what I try, I can not manage to get this conversion working.

There's no way of making this a "free" conversion.

A `&str` is a Unicode string encoded with UTF-8. This is a byte-oriented encoding. If you have UTF-16 (or the **different** but common UCS-2 encoding), there's no way to read one as the other. That's equivalent to trying to read a JPEG image as a PDF. Both chunks of data might be a string, but the encoding is important.

The first question is "do you really need to do that?". Many times, you can take data from one function and shovel it back into another function, never looking at it. If you can get away with that, that might be be best answer.

If you *do* need to transform it, then you have to deal with the errors that can occur. An arbitrary array of 16-bit integers *may not* be valid UTF-16 or UCS-2. These encodings have edge cases that can easily produce invalid strings. Null-termination is another aspect - Unicode actually allows for embedded NUL characters, so a null-terminated string can't hold all possible Unicode characters!

Once you've ensured that the encoding is valid <sup>1</sup> and figured out how many entries in the input vector comprise the string, then you have to decode the input format and re-encode to the output format. This is likely to require some kind of new allocation, so you are most likely to end up with a `String`, which can then be used most anywhere a `&str` can be used.

There is a built-in method to convert UTF-16 data to a String: [`String::from_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16). Note that it returns a `Result` to allow for these error cases. There's also [`String::from_utf16_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16_lossy), which replaces invalid encoded parts with the Unicode replacement character.

```
let name = [0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f]; 

let a = String::from_utf16(&name);
let b = String::from_utf16_lossy(&name);

println!("{:?}", a);
println!("{:?}", b);
```

If you are starting from a pointer to a `u16` or `WCHAR`, you will need to convert to a slice first by using [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html). If you have a null-terminated string, you need to find the `NUL` yourself and slice the input appropriately.

---

1: This is actually a great way of using types; a `&str` is **guaranteed** to be UTF-8 encoded, so no further check needs to be made. Similarly, the `WideCString` is likely to perform a check once upon construction and then can skip the check on later uses.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out, I was obviously completely lost and somehow assumed that the encoding of both types would be identical. In this context, it makes sense to use another String object (are they actually called objects in rust?) for this transformation,

Comment: @Norbert: I am not sure that rustaceans ponder about whether to call things objects or not; everyone just understands the term so it's good enough :)

Comment: @Norbert yeah, I think it depends on what you want to call an "object". If you mean a chunk of data and associated methods, then yeah, it is an object. I think I'd normally just say "type" instead of "class" and then just "instance of a type". I haven't found myself needing to say "object" frequently. I think everyone would understand you just fine though.

Comment: Great to read that rustaceans are not that religious about the use of such words or the aspects of the language :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is my simple hack for this case. There must be a bug; fix for your own case:

```
let mut v = vec![0u16; MAX_PATH as usize];

// imaginary win32 function
win32_function(v.as_mut_ptr());

let mut path = String::new();
for val in v.iter() {
    let c: u8 = (*val & 0xFF) as u8;
    if c == 0 {
        break;
    } else {
        path.push(c as char);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to go out of your way to not support non-ASCII values, but I'd write this as `let path: String = v.iter().map(|&v| (v & 0xFF) as u8).take_while(|&c| c != 0).map(|c| c as char).collect();`

Comment: thanks for the info, i am just novice for rust, scala, elixir.